# Python editor in a PyQt4 application

Tags: qt, user-interface, kparts

I need to integrate an editor into a window/dialog in my PyQt4 application.
It needs to support syntax highlighting for Python, Java and C++. It should run under Linux and ideally windows.
What would you suggest and where can I find the API and instructions?
I was thinking about Katepart, but I can't find instructions for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/intro

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/QScintilla2/index.html

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/01/sample-using-qscintilla-with-pyqt/

Comment: Also there is a plugin for Qt4-designer, which makes the use extremely easy. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. You might also want to check this question as answered.